# ¿como enviar una variable en una mail() de varias partes?

Tags: php, html

Buenas,
el problema que tengo es con un codigo para enviar mails con archivos adjuntos que encontré en la web y quiero modificarlo para enviar una variable, sin embargo al colocar la variable no me llega en el correo, ya verifique que la variable no esta vacía así que supongo que sera error mio o algo que desconozco aun.

```
    $id=$_GET['id'];

        //The form has been submitted, prep a nice thank you message
    $output = '<h1>!</h1>';
    //Set the form flag to no display (cheap way!)
    $flags = 'style="display:none;"';

    //Deal with the email
    $to = 'ganadores@ats.com';
    $subject = 'Subasta slip';

    $message = strip_tags($_POST['message']);
    $attachment = 
    chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'])));
    $filename = $_FILES['file']['name'];

    $boundary =md5(date('r', time())); 

    $headers = "From: cliente@acs.com\r\nReply-To: cliente@acs.com";
    $headers .= "\r\nMIME-Version: 1.0\r\nContent-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"_1_$boundary\"";

    $message="This is a multi-part message in MIME format.

 --_1_$boundary
 Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=\"_2_$boundary\"

 --_2_$boundary
 Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"
 Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
 //********************aquí es donde quiero enviar la variable****************
<h2>ID del producto</h2>
<p>".$id."</p> 

$message

--_2_$boundary--
--_1_$boundary
Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"$filename\" 
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64 
Content-Disposition: attachment 

$attachment
--_1_$boundary--";

    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Como nota al margen, me sirve cualquier forma de enviar la variable, solo necesito que se vea en alguna parte. Gracias de antemano

Comment: $id lo siento, olvide especificarlo

Comment: Prueba con: `<p>\"$id\"</p>`

Comment: No, aunque hubo un avance...  envía las comillas

Comment: Se que has comentado haber comprobado la variable, pero tiene pinta de estar vacía.

Comment: ¿Por que escapar la ID si de por sí se utilizan comillas dobles?, que por cierto, ¿que contiene?, por que no se declara... usa: `<p>$id</p>`

Comment: Ya he solucionado el problema, a decir verdad habia un error que estaba haciendo que la variable saliera vacía. Era algo que estaba totalmente fuera de mis expectativas, el action del formulario que estaba usando no estaba bien dirigido. Gracias a los dos por sus respuestas, me hicieron dudar de la cosa menos obvia ! Como estaba pasando una variable a traves de la dirección, y el formulario no se ejecutaba sobre la misma dirección al parecer el get no obtenía el valor ,mi logica me decia que no debia pasar, pero bueno perdonen las molestias y gracias de nuevo

Answer (score 0):

Como te comenté en el comentario, no hay necesidad de escapar nuevamente el ID.

El código tiene dos problemas:

- La variable ID no está definida, si la defines más arriba no debería haber problema.
- Falta un espacio después de la codificación, tiene que ir en una línea espaciada.

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/faa4844b22854a8576d4c668eebbca52

He creado un GIST por que no me escapaba correctamente el código aquí en Stack, he remplazado con XXX el email, recuerda cambiarlo.

Probado y funcionando con los datos DEMO que puse. Si has verificado que dichos datos se recogen y están correctamente declarados y procesados debería funcionar tal cual te lo pego (quitando las pruebas mías claro).

Saludos,